# AChartEngine - How to set the new format of xlabels runtime in TimeChart

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a TimeChart and intial dateformat is "MM-dd-yyyy" like below.

```
mChart = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getActivity(), mDataset, mRenderer,"MM-dd-yyyy");
```

now I want the format to be "MMM-yy" from "MM-dd-yyyy" without calling "ChartFactory.getTimeChartView" method again and create the whole chart view again.

Can this be possible ?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am currently in the same predicament, since I want to change my labels as the user zooms around, to reflect the highest x value currently visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that directly, but there are some other solutions like custom labels.

Comment: Yes, currently I am using the custom labels with the zoom listener to change the data from day wise to month wise. but I want it to be more simple that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for changing the format.

```
private static final int NUM_LABELS = 5;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mMultiRenderer;
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private GraphicalView mChart;

private void applyCustomXLabels(String format, boolean useFormat) {
    // Get the min and max (dates) in the current 'window'
    double min = mMultiRenderer.getXAxisMin();
    double max = mMultiRenderer.getXAxisMax();

    // Remove any custom x labels
    mMultiRenderer.clearXTextLabels();

    // If not using the custom format, allow the labels to be auto generated
    // using the default label generator
    if (!useFormat) {
        // Set the number of auto-generated labels
        mMultiRenderer.setXLabels(NUM_LABELS);
    } else {
        // Get evenly spaced label locations between min and max
        List<Double> labelLocations = MathHelper.getLabels(min, max, NUM_LABELS);
        // Go through each location
        for(Double d : labelLocations) {
            // Add a custom x label using the double as the location and format it to a date
            mMultiRenderer.addXTextLabel(d, new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(new Date(Math.round(d))));
        }
        // Remove the auto-generated x labels
        mMultiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    }
    // May or may not be needed
    mChart.repaint();
}
```

Now, keep in mind that once this has been called it will be useless as soon as you zoom or pan. To keep it useful implement the following:

```
private static final String NEW_LABEL_FORMAT = "MMM-yy";

private class ChartZoomListener implements ZoomListener {
    @Override
    public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent zoomEvent) {
        applyCustomXLabels(NEW_LABEL_FORMAT, true);
    }
    @Override
    public void zoomReset() { }
}

private class ChartPanListener implements PanListener {
    @Override
    public void panApplied() {
        applyCustomXLabels(NEW_LABEL_FORMAT, true);
    }
}


private void setupChart(){
    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.trends_chart_container);
    mChart = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getActivity().getBaseContext(), mDataset, mMultiRenderer, "MM-dd-yyyy");
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);
    mChart.addZoomListener(new ChartZoomListener(), true, true);
    mChart.addPanListener(new ChartPanListener());
}
```